# Raspberry Pi 3 USB Bare Metal

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, raspberry-pi3, bare-metal, usb-hostcontroller

I am working on the new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ board in a bare metal environment (32-bit). I have a working USB driver for the older Pi 1 boards. From what I understand, the Pi 1 and the Pi 3 B+ have the same USB host controller (Synopsis DesignWare 2.0 USB Host Controller; or dwc for short), yet the USB driver that works on the Pi 1 does not work for me on the Pi 3 B+ (or the Pi 3 B either).

After going through some debugging messages, I found that the problem is that when the DWC is enumerating the devices, it will try to read the device descriptor of, what I am guessing is, the on-board USB hub/ethernet device (LAN7515), but it will return a transfer error, and then therefore is unable to enumerate the device.

My question is why does this happen? If the Pi 1 and the Pi 3 have the same host controller then it should, in theory, at least be able to properly enumerate a device.

If someone can point me in the right direction as to why this happens, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd be very curious to see the solution to this enumeration issue. I have seen a few bare metal USB repositories on GitHub (e.g. https://github.com/rsta2/uspi). I have worked with bare metal Pi projects in the past, and you are correct that enumeration *should* work in theory, since the DWC peripheral has not changed. My guess is: your Pi 3 driver has some quirk in the initialization process where device attachment is made impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The Pi3 is having an alignment issue because some of the USB structures are not natively aligned and they are packed. It generally requires inserting some pack and alignment attributes "**attribute**((**packed**, aligned(1)))" on some of the structures that are unaligned.

The rule goes 
uint16_t* pointers must be reading/writing align 2 addresses
uint32_t* pointers must be reading/writing align 4 addresses

So a struct like this is misaligned.

```
struct BadStruct __attribute__((__packed__)){
     uint8_t a;
     uint16_t b;
};
```

Comment: I can see how this would cause an issue. Are there any structs in particular that need to have these attributes? or just all structs in general?